# Latexmk After TexLive Installation

Tags: latexmk

I am trying to compile some LaTeX using VSCode on linux. I just did the basic installation scheme of TexLive ( < 300 MB). When I try to compile some code though I get an error about latexmk not being found.

When I try to run latexmk from the terminal it says it can't be found.

I guess I thought it would included with the basic installation. I made sure to update all my paths immediately after installation.

Does anyone know why it can't be found? Or how I should remedy the situation? I apologize if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Why didn't you simply install texlive-full?

Comment: Apparently `latexmk` is not included in the basic scheme you installed. If you installed vanilla TeX live from TUG, you can install `latexmk` via `tlmgr` (`tlmgr install latexmk` or some such, possibly with `sudo`). If you installed TeX live from your Linux distribution's package repositories, you need to find out which package includes `latexmk` (in Ubuntu it appears to be called `latexmk`, so `sudo apt install latexmk` should do it, see https://packages.ubuntu.com/de/focal/latexmk)

Comment: @Johannes_B Because I am on a machine with very limited space

Comment: @moewe Thanks. I tried to install it with tlmgr, not sure it worked correctly. It installed really quick. I am doubtful though because when I tried to install it using sudo apt install latexmk it indicated the DL would be several hundred MB. It worked really really fast, seemingly instantly, with tlmgr. So just not sure. Either way, didn't appear to fix my problem. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Mhhh, this shouldn't be a free choice. **If** you installed vanilla TeX live, you absolutely should install `latexmk` via `tlmgr`. **If** you installed your TeX live from the distribution repository, you should install `latexmk` via `apt`.  `latexmk` is a very small Perl script, so it is plausible that the download would be very small. I can imagine that `apt` would pull in additional dependencies, especially if you installed vanilla TeX live, `apt install latexmk` may install a competing TeX system.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't say anything useful about the "Either way, didn't appear to fix my problem." You'll need to be more precise about what you did and how things don't work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on how it should be installed.